# shared_ptr with vector

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I currently have vectors such as:

```
vector<MyClass*> MyVector;
```

and I access using

```
MyVector[i]->MyClass_Function();
```

I would like to make use of `shared_ptr`. Does this mean all I have to do is change my `vector` to:

```
typedef shared_ptr<MyClass*> safe_myclass

vector<safe_myclass>
```

and I can continue using the rest of my code as it was before?

Comment: That better be `shared_ptr<MyClass>`

Comment: Ok but will shared_ptr<MyClass> allow me to replicate  vector<MyClass*> rather than vector<MyClass>? I am not using any polymorphism in my code.

Comment: `shared_ptr<MyClass>` is a pointer already, a shared pointer to a `MyClass` object. `shared_ptr<MyClass*>` would be a pointer to a pointer, or the raw equivalent of `MyClass**`.

Comment: Excellent, I thought as much. Thanks K-ballo

Comment: @K-ballo: "would be a pointer to a pointer" would be SMART pointer to pointer.

Comment: @user997112: Since you are not using polymorphism in your code, what is the need for a pointer in the first place? Why don't you just hole `MyClass` directly inside the vector?

Comment: @David, I use the vector as a temporary storage area whilst I manipulate MyClass and then I join different instances of MyClass together. When I wasnt using pointers, as soon as the vector was over-written I (obviously) lost the MyClass objects.

Answer (score 9):

Probably just `std::vector<MyClass>`.  Are you

1. working with polymorphic classes or
2. can't afford copy constructors or have a reason you can't copy and are sure this step doesn't get written out by the compiler?

If so then shared pointers are the way to go, but often people use this paradigm when it doesn't benefit them at all.

To be complete if you do change to `std::vector<MyClass>` you may have some ugly maintenance to do if your code later becomes polymorphic, but ideally all the change you would need is to change your typedef.

Along that point, it may make sense to wrap your *entire* std::vector.

```
class MyClassCollection {
     private : std::vector<MyClass> collection;
     public  : MyClass& at(int idx);
     //...
 };
```

So you can safely swap out not only the shared pointer but the entire vector.  Trade-off is harder to input to APIs that expect a vector, but those are ill-designed as they should work with iterators which you can provide for your class.

Likely this is too much work for your app (although it would be prudent if it's going to be exposed in a library facing clients) but these are valid considerations.

Comment: I used vector<MyClass*> because I was creating a chain of recursively linked elements and I needed them to still point to eachother even if I emptied the vector. Plus the fact I want automatic memory reclamation.

Comment: would a linked list make more sense as a container than a vector then?

Comment: Seems like you had some typos and used a C# syntax: `private` and `public` should be followed by ":".

Answer (score 9):

`vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>> MyVector;` should be OK.

But if the instances of `MyClass` are not shared outside the vector, and you use a modern C++11 compiler, `vector<unique_ptr<MyClass>>` is more efficient than `shared_ptr` (because `unique_ptr` doesn't have the ref count overhead of `shared_ptr`).

Comment: @Deqing not anymore in C++11

Comment: @nurettin .. it is in not anymore in "some" C+11 compilers.

Comment: @AJed Which non-confirming C++ compilers are they?

Comment: @nurettin I honestly don't know, but I cite the C++ Primer book (edition 5). They repeated this sentence many times in the book.

Comment: @AJed It's not a useful statement at all.

Comment: @nurettin Maybe for you, and I honestly don't care about what you think. But, I am sure you said something wrong, and I wanted to correct you.

Comment: @AJed calm down, it is a basic language feature which is in six C++11 compilers out there that I know and what you're defending is the author's subjective, unsubstantiated opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Don't immediately jump to shared pointers. You might be better suited with a simple [pointer container](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/) if you need to avoid copying objects.