# Deleting objects from a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have looked at a number of questions that are very similar but I still can't manage to fix this.

Consider the simple class:

```
class Obj
{
public:
    Obj(int moose);
    ~Obj();

private:
    int* val;
};


Obj::Obj(int num)
{
    val = new int;

    *val = num;
}


Obj::~Obj()
{
    printf("Cleanup");
    delete val;
}
```

Now I want to have a vector of pointers to objs. The source details the problem:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<Obj*> objs;

    Obj* o = new Obj(10);

    objs.push_back(o);

    objs.erase(objs.begin() + 0);

    // should have been deleted by now - I want the destructor to have been called
    // I have tried delete objs[0], casting to it and then deleting it.

    return 0;
}
```

The destructor in Obj is only called when the program has finished. I want it to be called when the object is erased from the vector.

Clarification: I am trying to delete the object using the reference from the vector. I cannot get it to do so. I know that the vector doesn't deallocate the memory. It just removes the reference from the vector. Can anyone provide code which would delete the object and call the destructor using a reference from the vector.

Edit:

Even after adding:

```
auto it = objs.begin() + 0;
delete *it;
objs.erase(it);
```

as suggested, the destructor of the Obj does not fire.

Comment: Then you'll have to use `delete` on it before erasing it, or use something like a container of smart pointers or Boost's `ptr_vector`.

Comment: `std::vector<>` doesn't destruct its elements, it simply removes them from the container. It's up to you to delete the memory.

Comment: You want to use shared_ptr or ptr_vector

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790161/shared-ptr-with-vector

Comment: Why are you having a pointer to an integer in your class? I hope you don't have that in your real code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Just for a simple allocation example.

Comment: Note that std::vector can copy temporary objects, so the destructor may be called, freeing the data, when there may be still pointers pointing to it. If you manage dynamic data with raw pointers, it is important to keep in mind the rule of three: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29

Comment: @0x499602D2 I figured. I cannot however get it to delete the element. Obj* ptr = objs[0];
    
    delete ptr;  It doesn't work.

Comment: @user923 What error exactly do you get when calling `delete ptr` ?

Comment: @user923 You don't have to concern yourself with the managing the memory manually - if you use a `std::shared_ptr<>` it will manage the pointer itself when destructed.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Why does there need to be a copy constructor? I assumed there was no copying done as it's simply a vector of object pointers, not objects.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan I am not getting an error. But the destructor is not firing. Shouldn't it if I am deleting the object?

Comment: @user923 Yes, it definitely should. Depending on your optimization level you might not be able to break inside it but it should indeed do the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a number of comments have pointed out, `vector.erase` only removes the elements from the vector. It does NOT try to delete any associated memory.
To delete the associated memory explicitly, you need to:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ...

    auto it = objs.begin() + i;
    delete *it;
    objs.erase(it);

}
```

Actually, in your case:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<Obj*> objs;

    Obj* o = new Obj(10);
    objs.push_back(o);    

    auto it = objs.begin();
    delete *it;
    objs.erase(it);

}
```

There are a number of other inconsistencies with your code and, better solutions for what you're trying to do, such as:

- Using a `vector<Obj>`:

  ```
  int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
  {
      std::vector<Obj> objs;
      objs.emplace_back(10);    

      auto it = objs.begin();
      objs.erase(it);
  }
  ```
- If you need to dynamically allocate your objects, but for some reason do not want the vector to handle that, you can use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, who will take care of the deallocation for you:

  ```
  int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
  {
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Obj>> objs;

      objs.emplace_back(new Obj(10));    

      auto it = objs.begin();
      objs.erase(it);
  }
  ```

Comment: Using your examples, I am still not getting the destructor of my Obj class to fire. That's the problem I have been having.

Comment: I have actually tested the three versions of the code I posted, and they all seem to properly destroy the object. One version briefly had a `delete[]` operator because I had misread your code, so maybe that's the version you're trying to use ?

Comment: Weird. Must be something with my code then. It really is just the code I posted above. Also, I realize it looks weird declaring memory on the heap and then using a vector of pointers but in my actual program, it's not used in this way.

Comment: The perks of posting an SSCCE ;)

Comment: Try it with just this code, and see if that works for you... if it does, that narrows down the problem to something else. Possibly the use of a derived class with a non-virtual destructor ?

Answer (score 1):

When you erase an element (which is a pointer) from a vector, you are just removing it from the container vector. But the location that the pointer was pointing to is still valid memory on heap. If you want to free that memory, you should use delete, and explicitly free the memory. If you do not want to manage the memory on your own, use smart pointers.

Comment: I still cannot get the destructor to fire when deleting the object.

Comment: Something similar to `delete objs[0]` will call the destructor. You should erase the object from the vector if you don't need it, but you should also call `delete o` or `delete objs[0]`.

Comment: How are you deleting the object and checking if the destructor was called before the program ended?

Answer (score 0):

When you erase an item from a vector, the destructor of the item will be called. But in this case the item is a pointer, and pointers don't *have* destructors. The object the pointer is pointing to will *not* have its destructor called until you use `delete` on the pointer. If the pointer is erased and you don't have another copy of it, you'll never be able to delete it and you'll have a memory leak.

Whenever possible, prefer to put the object itself in the vector rather than a pointer. That will relieve you of the chore of memory management.

Comment: Thank you. The particular problem I am having here though is that when I delete the object, the destructor doesn't fire until the program has ended.

Comment: @user923 you delete `val`, but to make that happen you have to delete `o` first. I don't see that in the code you posted.

Comment: auto it = objs.begin() + 0;
    delete *it;
    objs.erase(it);

Comment: Still does not call the destructor.