# Copy items from one vector to another vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to copy certain items from one vector into another vector which contains shared_ptr objects.

I don't want a reference but a unique copy of that object placed into the other vector.
The whole point of this is to fill listEnvironmentStatic with game object and when the game map starts, everything gets copied to listEnvironment for simulations and when the players wants to reset the map, listEnvironment copies everything from listEnvironmentStatic once again and every object is back to its original location.

```
    this->listEnvironment.insert(this->listEnvironment.end(), this->listEnvironmentStatic.begin(), this->listEnvironmentStatic.end());
```

using the std::copy and resizing the second vector does't work either.

Look a the following example:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Environment>> listEnvironmentStatic;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Environment>> listEnvironment;
```

Now lets say i have a couple of items in listEnvironmentStatic that i want to copy over to listEnvironment (which always contains at least 1 object), how would I do unique copy and still keep the listEnvironmentStatic in case the player wants to restart the map once again?

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to use `shared_ptr` in containers like `vectors`. See, for example, [Is using std::vector< std::shared_ptr<const T> > an antipattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24085931) and [shared_ptr with vector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10790161).

Comment: Do you want to append into `listEnviroment` or replace everything in it?

Comment: And if list2 always contains one object, why is it a vector?

Comment: "The whole idea with this is to reset the game map back to its origin." That makes no sense unless you explain it.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. If you have a `shared_ptr<A> a = ...;` and you want a new instance of `A` which is copied, use `auto b = std::make_shared< A >( *a );` (or the equivalent when "copying" elements from vector to vector).

Comment: I have updated my question so it makes more sense. What i meant was, listEnvironment always contains at least 1 object, it is never empty

Comment: @nilo What do you mean by "I don't one to increase the reference count nor have a referens to the original container what so ever." (even with one=want)

Comment: I have updated the question once again to make it as clear as possible. so sorry guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want new instances which are copies from the originating vector, you could use:

```
for ( const auto& e : listEnvironmentStatic )
    listEnvironment.push_back( std::make_shared<Environment>( *e ) );
```

Comment: What if Environment is a abstract base class?

Comment: @nilo In that case you need to add some method `clone()` to the class and its derived classes which can provide a copy. Each (most derived) class would know how to create a copy of itself (using `std::make_shared<D>(*this);`) and return the shared pointer from `clone()`. Then use `listEnvironment.push_back( e->clone() );`.

Comment: So basically add a virtual std::shared_ptr<Environment> Clone() = 0; And then do std::shared_ptr<Environment> Clone() { return std::make_shared<Environment>(*this); } ?

Comment: @nilo Almost, except that you need the derived class' name in `std::make_shared< DerivedFromEnvironment >( *this );`. Or just `std::make_shared< typename std::decay<decltype(*this)>::type >( *this );`

Comment: Works mate, you are the best